# Program freezes with specific numbers

Tags: vb.net

This code is supposed to take a number and find it's prime factors.

Why does this code work with numbers like 2345 (which returns 5, 7, 67 like its supposed to) but it doesn't work with numbers like 500 and 800?

EDIT: when I say it doesn't work, the program simply does nothing and/or freezes on button click. I then have to stop the program in vb.

```
    Dim number As Double = txtNum.Text
    Dim var As Double = 2
    Dim result As Double
    If number > 1 Then
        lst1.Items.Clear()
        lst1.Items.Add("The prime factors of " & number & ":")
        Do While number > 1
            result = number / var
            If result = Int(result) Then
                lst1.Items.Add(var)
                number = result
            End If
            var = var + 1
        Loop
    Else
        lst1.Items.Clear()
        lst1.Items.Add("Let try that again...")
    End If
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What does it do?  What do you expect it to do?  Why?  When you step through in your debugger, where does the actual behavior first differ from the expected behavior?  What are the values of the variables when that happens?

Comment: A) Please read [ask] B) take the [tour] C) set `option Strict On` D) if it is VB.NET, it cant be vba E) describe the problem better

Comment: `"the program simply does nothing and/or freezes"` - This is a great time to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime values and behaviors.

Comment: @YowE3K this was the answer I was looking for, thank you

Comment: `sigh.. first post not working out too well`  Yeah, thats why there is [ask], the [help] and the [tour].  So new users can learn how the site works, post *good* questions and get the help they need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because 500 divided by 2 is 250, divided by 5 is 50 ... and then the program continued on by dividing by 6 instead of attempting to divide by 5 again. Once `var` reached 10, `number` became 5 and no further divisions ever allowed it to reach 1 - thus an infinite loop was created.

By changing

```
If result = Int(result) Then
    lst1.Items.Add(var)
    number = result
End If
var = var + 1
```

to

```
If result = Int(result) Then
    lst1.Items.Add(var)
    number = result
Else
    var = var + 1
End If
```

it correctly made multiple divisions by the same prime factor when necessary.